# Segoe UI bugs when compiled to android application

Tags: android, delphi, fonts, delphi-10-seattle

I'm using **Delphi 10 Seattle** to develop an **android application**.
I have this weird problem with the **Segoe UI font**.
(the same problem happens with other fonts, but in my case I want to use Segoe UI which is the (Default))

When the property **fsBold** in TextSettings/font/style is set to **true**, the text gets kinda "Cut" as you can see in the image bellow.

[image: Problem]

Now when I compille the same application to Windows 32 bit, the font works just fine, as shown bellow.

[image: Windows Version]

These are my TextSettings

[image: Property Settings]

ps: Sorry for the image resolutions.

I just want to understand why this happens, is there a problem with Segoe UI on android?
am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you really expect to find that MS font on Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default **AutoSize** property in `Label` was set to `false`. Setting it to `true` fixes the problem.